# Windows Logon Events Description

Tags: windows, login, windows-event-log

Is there like any portal/site where I can refer to for the detailed description for WEV logins? Eg. 4625 An account failed to log on, 4723 An attempt was made to change an account's password and 4741 A computer account was created.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at: https://www.ultimatewindowssecurity.com/securitylog/encyclopedia/default.aspx